# Creating new array based on first element of each item in current array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, conditional-statements, slice

Please forgive me if my terminology isn't correct - I'm new to this!

I'm trying to isolate certain entries based on the value of the first element in each item in an array and perform some operations on certain columns. Here's an example of the type of data I'm working with:

```py
[[1, 99, 400],
[1, 95, 200],
[2, 92, 100],
[1, 85, 500],
[2, 88, 300]]
```

I need to figure out the means of columns 2 and 3 using a `for loop`, `if statement`, and arithmetic, respectively, for each condition (reflected in column 1, where values are either 1 or 2).

I'm trying to split the above array into two separate arrays for each condition, and then taking the mean of those columns using `numpy.mean`. 
 Here's what I want the lists to look like:

```py
cond1 = [[1, 99, 400], [1, 95, 200], [1, 85, 500]]
cond2 = [[2, 92, 100], [2, 88, 300]]
```

I'm stuck on how to separate these conditions into two new arrays based on the first element. Here's the furthest I've gotten after googling about slicing.. but I'm stuck!

```py
for x in stim:
    if stim_acc[0]==1.0:
        np.where(stim_acc[0] = 1.0)
        cond1 = [[s,a,rt] for s, a, rt in zip(stim, acc, mrt)]
        print(cond1)
```

regarding `stim`, `acc`, and `mrt`:

I have a several column-long set of data from which I isolated the stimulus (now `stim`), accuracy (now `acc`), and mean reaction time (now `mrt`) entries into a new list (the first in this post). I did this like so:

```
stim = data[:,1]
 acc = data[:,3]
 mrt = data[:,4]

 stim_acc = [[s, a, rt] for s, a, rt in zip(stim, acc, mrt)]
 print(stim_acc)
```

I've preemptively named the new list `stim_acc` because i foresaw this turning into a list calculating the accuracy for each condition over a loop.

Thank you, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use pandas `.groupby()`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what stim, acc, mrt are meant to be. Can you paste the full code snipet?

Comment: Just added an explanation for stim, acc, and mrt - let me know if you need more info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand, you want to split your list to two list by index[0]'s value. If it is 1 then add to `cond1`'s list, else add to `cond2`'s list. You can implement this using this code:

```
cond1=[]
cond2=[]
for item in listoflists:
    if item[0] == 1:
        cond1.append(item)
    else 
        cond2.append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

use pandas `groupby` :

```
>>> a = [[1, 99, 400],
 [1, 95, 200],
 [2, 92, 100],
 [1, 85, 500],
 [2, 88, 300]]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(a)
>>> df
   0   1    2
0  1  99  400
1  1  95  200
2  2  92  100
3  1  85  500
4  2  88  300
>>> data = df.groupby([0])
>>> cond = data.groups
>>> df.loc[cond[1]]
   0   1    2
0  1  99  400
1  1  95  200
3  1  85  500
>>> df.loc[cond[2]]
   0   1    2
2  2  92  100
4  2  88  300
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple loop, you can display the means like this:

```
data=[[1, 99, 400],
[1, 95, 200],
[2, 92, 100],
[1, 85, 500],
[2, 88, 300]]

groups = [], []
for row in data:
    groups[row[0]-1].append(row)

for group in groups:
    print(np.mean(group, axis=0))  # means of each column by group
```

But it is often better to use a pandas dataframe for this type of task

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["stim", "acc", "mrt"])
for value in df.stim.unique():
    print(df[df.stim == value].mean())
```

or

```
for i, group in df.groupby("stim"):
    print(i, group.mean())
```

(I'm assuming you want the means of each column within each group.)